# .NET C# Google Apis - invalid grant exception

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I am beginning to work with the Google Api (the .NET version). 
- I've initialized a VS 2010/.NET 4.0 project using NuGet to get current libs.
- I've created Google console project and ensured APIs for Google+ and Google Analytics.v3 are enabled in it
- I've created an X509 cert for use to authenticate. Authentication appears to work.
- I use my google email address as it owns all projects and is the api almighty role.
- I have synchronized time to north-america.pool.ntp.org ... just to ensure my time is similar to Google time.

Problem: No matter the service - Analytics or Plus - I get an invalid_grant exception thrown. I've no idea why ... other forums suggest this is a time issue, but I think, at least, I have addressed this concern by setting time servers to what Google appears to use.

Code for what I am doing is shown as follows:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plus API - Service Account");
        Console.WriteLine("==========================");

        String serviceAccountEmail = EMAIL_ADDRESS;

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\tmp\PrivateKey3.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Plus API Sample",
        });

        Activity activity = service.Activities.Get(ACTIVITY_ID).Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("  Activity: " + activity.Object.Content);
        Console.WriteLine("  Video: " + activity.Object.Attachments[0].Url);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Failure occurs/exception is thrown at the service.Activities.Get() line of code. Can anyone assist and help me understand the root cause and possible fixes?

Comment: I have tried registering the developer service account email associated with my google analytics account with my registered app and gave it edit privilege ... with the same outcome ... I don't suppose this should work with Plus, but I tried nonetheless ...

Comment: Is it possible that the X509-based auth is not working? The auth call succeeds, but the rest fails ...

Answer (score 1):

The EMAIL_ADDRESS var needs to be the email address created when you setup your API access in the API  console ( not your gmail address). If you are dealing with google apps the apps administrators will need to give your API client ID access to the oath scope you are trying to access. 
In the serviceacountcredential class there is a property you set to impersonate a specific user.

You also should import and query the local cert store on the server for that certificate. It holds public and private keys and should not be stored on te file system.